# How to optimize zlib compression level?

Tags: linux, compression

I want to compress a file using Zlib (Best compression) i have googled a bit around and i have found a way to compress, but it isn't at the best compression level, I'd love to get some help

OS Details:
Parrot Security OS Release 3.11 64-Bit
Kernel Linux 4.14.0-parrot13-amd64 x86_64
MATE 1.18.0

Comment: `gzip --best` will do that.

Comment: That isn't a zlib compressed file though

Comment: Yes it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762094/how-are-zlib-gzip-and-zip-related-what-do-they-have-in-common-and-how-are-they

Answer (score 1):

According to my tests the [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/) utility will do it like so...

> pigz -z9 < file2Compress > outCompressedFile

Alternatively

> zlib-flate -compress < yourFile2Compress > compressedFileName

However zlib-flate will only do default compression.